# While loop in Ruby with a time interval

Tags: ruby, time, while-loop

How to put a time interval of one second in a Ruby while loop ? So that the loop loops for 30 seconds. It's a generator for bingo numbers.

```
while i < 30 # BrojacPocetak petlje.

  slucajno_generisan_broj = rand(1..49) # Slucajno generisan broj od 1 do 49.

  if izvuceni_brojevi.any? {|n| n == slucajno_generisan_broj} # Provjera dali je generisani broj vec u nizu.
    next # Vraca na pocetak petlje, ako broj vec postoji u nizu.
  else
    izvuceni_brojevi << slucajno_generisan_broj # Inace ako generisan broj ne postoji u nizu, ova linija ga dodaje na vrh niza.
    i = i+1 # Index se povecava za 1.
  end # Kraj if petlje.

end
```

Comment: I don't think the comments in the code help the majority of the readers, and is rather noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a `sleep 1` at the end of the while block:

```
while i < 30
  ...
  sleep 1
end
```